# Angular Firestore: Randomize query result

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

If I have a code below to reference all records and sync for changes:

```
this.productsRef.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
```

How do I randomize the order of the documents I get but retain the synchronization of the collection and documents to Firestore?

UPDATED: I played around a bit, this seems to work:

```
import { shuffle } from "lodash";
...    
this.productsRef.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).subscribe((res:Product[])=> {
   this.products = shuffle(res);
});
```

Comment: If the update is the answer, then please post it as is, not as an update to the question post

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm still waiting for better solutions.

Comment: The workaround you have found seems good, but you can add `uniq()` in the third line i.e., `this.products = uniq(shuffle(res));` so that documents will appear only once.

Comment: It seems the values are already unique when using `this.products = shuffle(res)`

Comment: I have updated my answer below. please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment into answer

The workaround you have found seems good, but you can add `uniq()` in the third line i.e.,

```
this.products = uniq(shuffle(res));
```

so that documents will appear only once. As mentioned in the [Documentation 1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-uniq-method/)

> The _.uniq method is used to create an array of unique values in order, from all given arrays using SameValueZero for equality comparisons.

And as per the [Documentation 2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-shuffle-method/), the `shuffle()` method

> The _.shuffle() method creates an array of shuffled values from the given collection using a version of the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm.

Comment: It seems the values are already unique when using `this.products = shuffle(res)`

Comment: Can you check with the [Documentation1](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-shuffle-method/#:~:text=The%20_.shuffle()%20method%20creates%20an%20array%20of%20shuffled%20values%20from%20the%20given%20collection%20using%20a%20version%20of%20the%20Fisher%2DYates%20shuffle%20algorithm) and [Documentation2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-uniq-method/#:~:text=The%20_.uniq%20method%20is%20used%20to%20create%20an%20array%20of%20unique%20values%20in%20order%2C%20from%20all%20given%20arrays%20using%20SameValueZero%20for%20equality%20comparisons.%C2%A0)